# Better way to get a list of files in a given directory

Tags: ruby

When I need to work with files in a given directory, I always resort to the following way, which to my opinion is cumbersome:

```
    this_dir = Dir.pwd
    filepath = File.join(this_dir, "directory")
    file_list = Dir[File.join(filepath, "*.txt")]
```

I know that the code below returns an array of filenames. Supposedly there is only one file in that directory, the way I'm used to reaching to is:

```
    File.basename(file_list[0])
```

Are there better and tidier ways to get a list of files in a directory, so that I can do whatever I want with these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's some things to note here. In many cases file operations are *presumed* to work based on your current working directory, `Dir.pwd`, so that does not need to be specified.

The easiest way to find the first matching file is:

```rb
Dir['directory/*.txt'].first
```

There's not much to be gained here over your `file_list` approach, except that you don't need all the preamble.

Comment: There's also `Dir['*.txt', base: 'directory']` which returns just the filenames.